# A fixed size Dictionary with substitution priority

Tags: c#, dictionary, fixed

I want to have a fixed-size dictionary. I am adding to it elements with a high frequency. But I want it to substitute the newer elements with higher priority with previous ones.
Any help would be highly welcomed.

Comment: The data structure you've described is not a dictionary - it's a fix-length queue.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: But I need to add a pair of Key,Value to it that later can be retrieved by value

Comment: The structure that I need is a hash but with a good substitution strategy

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek : I need fast look-ups

Comment: how does the priority works? Is it the key? or each data object has like value, priority and key?

Comment: I guess by now you don't need the solution but you can always create a class that inherits from IDictionary and override it's Add method to prevent dictionary from growing beyond a particular size

Answer (score 1):

I guess by now you don't need the solution but you can always create a class that inherits from IDictionary and override it's Add method to prevent dictionary from growing beyond a particular size

Something like this

```
class LimitedSizeDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
 Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict;
 Queue<TKey> queue;
 int size;

 public LimitedSizeDictionary(int size)
 {
 this.size = size;
 dict = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(size + 1);
 queue = new Queue<TKey>(size);
 }

 public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
 {
 dict.Add(key, value);
 if (queue.Count == size)
 dict.Remove(queue.Dequeue());
 queue.Enqueue(key);
 }

 public bool Remove(TKey key)
 {
 if (dict.Remove(key))
 {
 Queue<TKey> newQueue = new Queue<TKey>(size);
 foreach (TKey item in queue)
 if (!dict.Comparer.Equals(item, key))
 newQueue.Enqueue(item);
 queue = newQueue;
 return true;
 }
 else
 return false;
 }
}
```